# How to set up a react app to work with carousel without fading images the image

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-bootstrap

```
import React from 'react';
import { Carousel } from 'react-bootstrap';
import "./HomePage.css";
import img1 from '../../img/car_polising.jpg';
import img2 from '../../img/polishing-light.jpg';
import img3 from '../../img/spoljasnje-pranje-vozila.jpg';


export default class HomePage extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Carousel controls={false} >
  <Carousel.Item>
    <img
      className="d-block w-100"
      src={img1}
      alt="First slide"
    />
    <Carousel.Caption>
      <h3>First slide label</h3>
      <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
    </Carousel.Caption>
  </Carousel.Item>
  <Carousel.Item>
    <img
      className="d-block w-100"
      src={img2}
      alt="Second slide"
    />

    <Carousel.Caption>
      <h3>Second slide label</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </Carousel.Caption>
  </Carousel.Item>
  <Carousel.Item>
    <img
      className="d-block w-100"
      src={img3}
      alt="Third slide"
    />

    <Carousel.Caption>
      <h3>Third slide label</h3>
      <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
    </Carousel.Caption>
  </Carousel.Item>
</Carousel>
        )
    }
}
```

When I launch the application, the first image disappears and only then the next one appears.
There is no real slide where one image pushes another. I don't understand what the problem is.
React app works in strict mode. When I throw out strict mode it behaves the same.